# Fusion table Current location

Tags: javascript, fusion

I'm trying to insert my current location in fusion tables.

Can anyone help?

My current code is:

```
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    mapDiv.style.width = isMobile ? '100%' : '500px';
    mapDiv.style.height = isMobile ? '100%' : '300px';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.532616713472365, -8.901311618652244),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


<body>
  <div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's not working? What have you tried?

Comment: i was abble to insert the geolocation and it works in google chrome but it doesn't work in android...